# Navigation method RouterLink does not work in Angular 10

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, angular10

I am using Angular 10 in Asp.net MVC project.

I am getting below error in the routing.
Here is my routing code.

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { StoreComponent } from './store/store.component';
import { CartComponent } from './cart/cart.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: StoreComponent },
  { path: 'cart', component: CartComponent }
];

@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StoreComponent } from './store/store.component';
import { CartComponent } from './cart/cart.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StoreComponent,
    CartComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/']">Store</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/cart']">Cart</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

So as per the code is has two menus, store and cart and expected result respectively is,

store works!

cart works!

But is shows blank page with no error in console.

Comment: Try adding the following to your first path: `{ path: '', component: StoreComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },`

Comment: @JeremyLucas Tried.It gave errror "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"